# Query Logs for filter non-empty strings in Google Cloud Logs Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to query for all logs that meets a simple condition:

The `jsonPayload` of some `DEFAULT` log entries have the following structure:

```js
response: {
    Values: [
        [   ] 
    ]
}
```

where each item in `Values` is an array. In most cases, `Values` have a single item `""` in the array (empty). I want to write a query that can filter all logs entry that have values different from an empty string (an array in fact).

Here's the query I tried to run:

```
severity="DEFAULT" AND
jsonPayload.response.Values != ''
```

This did not return any result. There are thousands of entries, most of which are empty. Can this be done? If so, what am I missing in this case?

**Edit**

I am checking to see if the first value inside `Values` is something other than an empty string. In entries I am looking for, the value of the first item will be an array.

**Edit 2**

Following the reference suggested, I tried looking for the opposite:

```
severity="DEFAULT" AND
jsonPayload.response.Values = ''
```

This shows me the all the results with empty Values array as expected. What's confusing me is why it's not working. The logs are generated by a cloud function that serves as a webhook for event processing. The `jsonPayload` represents the body of the request from the event source.

Comment: Maybe you need to search for [missing fields](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#missing_fields)? Also I couldn't find anything in docs for the syntax you're using. I only found that comparisons on an [array type](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#object_array_types) search for any matching array element.

Comment: Does `-jsonPayload.response.Values=''` work by any chance ?

Comment: I was able to download the logs and then use JS over the JSON log file to find the desired result. I tried with single quotes but that didn't work either

Comment: Does it work now or not?

Comment: Please have a look at this part of de documentation about [Advanced logs query syntax](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#advanced_logs_query_syntax) where you may use a query with the precedent ["NOT"] also it may be useful to [create an exclusion filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#create-filter) after you find a valid query

Comment: Have you tried with : severity="DEFAULT" AND
jsonPayload.response.Values !~ '' as seen in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

To filter non-empty strings in Google Cloud Logs Explorer as seen in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language):

```
severity="DEFAULT" AND
jsonPayload.response.Values !~ ''
```

Another way would be:

```
severity="DEFAULT" AND
jsonPayload.response.Values:*
NOT jsonPayload.response.Values = ''
```

Comment: It looks like typo error in the query-1. = symbol shouldn't be there since !~ represents the regex for search not for a pattern. Also severity="DEFAULT" AND
jsonPayload.response.Values != ' ' should work for non-empty strings since != refers to not equal to empty strings.